# Javascript - check selection box for invalid combination of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a selection box on my site which allows the user to check either "all" or a selection of specific items. The problem is that if they select "all" plus one or more items, it fouls up my search logic. What's the best way to check for this invalid combination in javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to take a boolean for `all` field. If they have selected "all" then make it true otherwise false.

If there are check boxes from user can select then check all the checkboxes programmatically when user click on "all".

If user select any check-box then first make that variable false and uncheck the "all" field programmatically.

Now when you apply your search logic first check for this boolean values if it's true then don't consider other selection values and if it's false then consider only other values.

For making this possible you just have to two classes, one for all field and another for other fields to get the changed/click trigger through jQuery.

I've given example with taking boolean variable but you can also apply other method you like but logic won't fail.

Answer (score 0):

If they select all then how come they can select "plus one or more items", because all are already selected.

Let's say it's a checkbox list, if the user selects "all" and then clicks on any other option then that option will be unselected and the select "all" option should also be unselected.